# how to define bindings for multiple keymaps with bind-keys?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, bind-key.el

I use [bind-key](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el) and I haven't found anything else that convenient for organizing key bindings. However sometimes I want to bind some commands for more keymaps than one. That's the way I do it now for both maps.

```
  (bind-keys  :map some-map
               :prefix-map some-prefix-map
               :prefix "PKEY"
               ("KEY1" . command1)
               ("KEY2" . command2))
```

and I want it to also work this way

```
  (bind-keys  :map map1 map2
               :prefix-map some-prefix-map
               :prefix "PKEY"
               ("KEY1" . command1)
               ("KEY2" . command2))
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
  (bind-keys :map org-mode-map emacs-lisp-mode-map
              :prefix-map f14-prefix-map
              :prefix "<f14>"
              ("x" . my-elisp-indent)
              ("y" . paredit-open-round)
              ("z" . paredit-kill))
```

Comment: Do you have a specific example? Sometimes there is a keymap which is common to both modes, e.g. `prog-mode-map` for programming modes.

Comment: I usually define my bindings only in `major-mode` maps. It feels "cleaner" than attaching them to `minor-mode` maps. So I'm not expecting any overlapping.

Comment: `prog-mode` is not a minor mode, it's a major mode from which major modes for source-code edition should inherit. Its purpose is to provide hooks which will be executed by all these modes, a keymap from which all these modes will inherit, and so on. And bnding keys in major modes is not cleaner than in minor modes, it's a matter of purpose.

Comment: Again, do you have an example of functions and maps for your question?

Comment: Indeed I don't think you have a ready-made solution for this usecase. What you do is could create a function defining these bindings and add the function to `org-mode-hook` and `emacs-lisp-mode-hook`. Not a full solution, but less code duplication at least.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve hooks.

Comment: Is there anything more annoying than someone asking you why you need something when it's perfectly obvious. The bind keys could take a list of mode-maps I suspect. It's very common to assign a function binding to disparate modes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate over the list of modes:

```
(dolist (m (list org-mode-map emacs-lisp-mode-map))
  (bind-keys :map m
             :prefix-map f14-prefix-map
             :prefix "<f14>"
             ("x" . my-elisp-indent)
             ("y" . paredit-open-round)
             ("z" . paredit-kill)))
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This answer no longer works, with more recent versions of the `bind-keys` package.

Just put the maps in a list, like so:

```el
(bind-keys :map (org-mode-map emacs-lisp-mode-map)
           :prefix-map f14-prefix-map
           :prefix "<f14>"
           ("x" . my-elisp-indent)
           ("y" . paredit-open-round)
           ("z" . paredit-kill))
```

One caveat: Last time I checked, the `bind-keys` handler for `use-package` doesn't recognize this syntax, so this won't work in a `:bind` statement inside `use-package`.

Comment: The docu specifies that :map should be a single map and NOT a list of maps. This doesn't work for me.

Comment: No this does not work with use-package and :bind. A shame.

Comment: It doesn't even work with the `bind-keys` form.